Why does my Kitchenaid top load washer agitator only spin one way?
I have a Kitchenaid KAWE560WWH1 top load washer (about 20 years old). It is direct drive.
The agitator works when just running unloaded or only a couple items. Once a regular load goes in the agitator stills works but only moves clothes in one direction (counterclockwise) and they end up wrapping around the agitator and makes a clunking sound. Both top and bottom of agitator move but only spinning clothes in a counterclockwise direction.
The tub still spins in spin cycle. I have replaced the agitator "dogs" or clogs but that was not the full issue. Any thoughts into the problem?

striped gear box ?
